# Redmine : error in running redmine_wktime plugin : rufus-scheduler-3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm using redmine 3.3.1

and i wanna install the plugin "redmine_wktime"

DOCUMENTATION of the plugin : https://github.com/dhanasingh/redmine_wktime,

As the documentation says i need to :

1) import the plugin files to the plugins folder of my redmine folder : /opt/redmine/redmine-3.3.1/plugins/  **(DONE)**

2) update the rails schema by running this :

rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_wktime RAILS_ENV=production   **(DONE)**

3) giving the read acces to the folder :

/opt/redmine/redmine-3.3.1/public/plugin_assets/redmine_wktime/   **(DONE)**

4) bundle install   **(DONE)**

5) restarting apache : service apache2 restart   **(DONE)**

until this step everything was done without any problemes or errors messages :

but when i'm trying to running the redmine application at localhost 
i'm getting this error , and it says that something goes wrong with **"rufus-scheduler-3.0.3**"

> Could not find rufus-scheduler-3.0.3 in any of the sources
>   (Bundler::GemNotFound)
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in
>   `block in materialize'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in`
>   map!'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in
>   `materialize'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in`
>   specs'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in
>   `specs_for'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in`
>   requested_specs'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in
>   `block in definition_method'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in`
>   setup'   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in
>   `setup'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in`
>   '
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
>   `require'
>
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`rescue
>   in require'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in
>   `require'
>
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in`
>   block in run_load_path_setup_code'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in
>   `running_bundler'
>
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in`
>   run_load_path_setup_code'
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in
>   `preload_app'
>
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in`
>   '
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in
>   `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
>
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in`'

[image]

***what should i do ???***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved by running simply:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

instead of just:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: it's my own response , i cannot accept it before 2 days  (i will do it as it would be available)